# Is evaluating C expression in the function argument violating MISRA C guideline?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, misra

Now think about the following piece of code being executed in a safety critical embedded software where `gcc_optimization_level` is Level2 for size. Say a function, `void foo(float v);` is invoked as `foo(a/b);` where say `a` and `b` are also `float`. Is evaluating a C expression `a/b` when invoking the function `foo` violating any MISRA C guideline?

ps: This question is revised from the previous version that was weakly formulated last week. Now this question ensures that it is a single question, not a homework question and hopefully not driving an opinion.

Comment: Why not write this code and run through MISRA checker? MISRA is overly restrictive standard, and I would not be surprised even such innocent things might be flagged.

Comment: Anyway, looking at MISRA-C guidelines I do not see anything that would restrict expression evaluation in the function call.

Comment: How is "compiler-optimization" (tagged, and mentioned some specific compiler) related to MISRA? I would say the code breaks advisory rule that you should use `float32_t` instead of `float`. But MISRA 2008 pdf is available on google - did you read it? Did you try searching which rules you might break? Can you show really full code instead of fragments? Which specific rules do you fear such code might break? And how is it related to optimization?

Comment: Is there some requirement about checking for overflow or divide-by-zero in the division `a/b`?  Perhaps doing it in a function call expression makes that harder to comply with?

Comment: Dear @EugeneSh. Is there any MISRA checker that I could plug this code and check it? I used to have an IDE that could do these checks but I don't have the license for that IDE anymore :(

Comment: Dear @KamilCuk, I did search the PDFs and some html pages out there but nothing matched my search strings like evaluating expression in function arguments. Hence, I posted the question here to see if you folks have come across anything like this before. Good points there about float32_t something that is usually skipped. I am sorry I am unable to show the full code as it belongs to the customer. Hence, I have summarized the problem to the best of my abilities. I hope this is okay. I worry that optimization might result in undefined behavior from what was intended, perhaps delayed division.

Comment: Good point about boundary conditions @NateEldredge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in MISRA C that prevents calling `foo( a / b )` as long as the types are correct.

Within MISRA C the concept of `essential types` is an attempt to introduce stronger typing to the C language - this is detailed in Appendix D of MISRA C:2012, with the Rule 10.x guidelines being the enforcement.

Equally, there is nothing in MISRA C that discusses optimization levels, beyond section 4.2 "Understanding the compiler" and section 5.3.1 "Compiler configuration" which discuss requisite knowledge (not detailing any guidelines).  These sections now form part of the [(freely downloadable) MISRA Compliance](https://misra.org.uk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=vfArSqzP1d0%3D&tabid=57).

Disclaimer: see profile.

Comment: My take is that this would however have been a MISRA-C violation in case the function was declared as `void foo (double);` . `a / b` should be what MISRA calls "composite expression" and then there's a rule 10.6 against assigning it to a wider variable of same essential type. This assuming that function calls are regarded as assignment by MISRA, since that's how the C standard treats them.

Comment: Yes, but the OP has `void foo( float )` so we're OK?

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, I am happy with your answer. Thanks to others for your valuable inputs, I felt enriched with your comments! Thanks!